# node.js error connect ENOTSOCK

Tags: node.js

While using node.js when i run the node script i get this error don't know where i made an error

```
events.js:72
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
```

Error: connect ENOTSOCK
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:895:19)

here is my script code which i used for connecting server

```
    var net = require('net');
// createConnection
var connection = net.createConnection({port: 8181, host:'/path/to/local_host/',path:'/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs'},
// connectListener callback
    function() {
        console.log('connection successful');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [createConnection](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_net_createconnection_options_connectionlistener) method only accepts path as a string parameter, which is the path to the unix socket.

```
var connection = net.createConnection('/path/to/socket/', function(socket) {
        console.log('connection successful');
});
```

If you're wanting to connect to a TCP socket, remove the path from the options object.

Comment: thanks for reply Ben , i was making a silly mistake my node server is closed that was the only problem thanks.